# How to disable stopOnEntry for files that are opened without a workspace?

Tags: python, configuration, visual-studio-code

When I open a python file without a workspace and start debugging it, the debugger breaks on the first line. I would like to change this behaviour, but I don't know how to do it for files that are opened without a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Open launch.json (gear icon when on debugger tab).  Find the section for the python debugger you are using.  Change "stopOnEntry" from true to false.  Save.